# How can I request music from K. K. Slider?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

I went to Club LOL to get a song today and, much to my surprise, KK didn't request a song title or give me any options at all. I pressed A to talk to him and he immediately decided to play K.K. Adventure.

In past games I was always able to either request a song by name or let him pick; I had no such option this time. How do I request specific music from KK Slider? Was this just something that happens the first time you "request" music, or is music always random now?

Comment: Maybe you can wait a night? The first time I tried to talk to him he just played a bunch of repeating songs. I'm pretty sure it was cause I didn't get there early enough and didn't wait a night.

Comment: It's confirmed that the first time a character requests a song, it is random. After the first time, you can request any song. I've tried it with all character slots and I get the same reaction. My friend got the same reaction, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm *fairly* sure that the very first time you talk to him, he will automatically play something. However, I can't completely confirm this at the moment. The following method may work the first time, but as I've already spoken to him and had my first encounter, I can't try it.

What I can confirm is this:

In order to request music from K.K., you need to back out of the first conversation with him. When he asks if you want him to play the first time you talk to him in an evening, decline, or else he will automatically pick a song to play at random. I tried this tonight because I didn't want to be given another random song like last week, and it worked.

When you talk to him a subsequent time, he will give you 3 options:
- Request a song ("I know a song!")
- He'll suggest one based on a certain mood ("Here's my mood...")
- He'll choose randomly ("I'll let you pick")

The last option you'll have is to back out, which is "Never mind." You can keep on requesting songs for the duration of his stay on Saturdays, but you'll only receive a copy of the song for the first song of the night.

Comment: Will have to try this next week, sounds plausible though. Very very many things in this game are different the first time around (which makes sense)

Comment: The first time he just plays something, if you talk to him after that you can request something.

Answer (score 0):

On Saturday evenings, K.K. Slider will show up, sitting on the edge of the stage and practicing on his guitar. From there, you can either tell him how are you feeling, or if you know a song, input it.